# Use get_option with $emailTo on contact page

Tags: php, options, contact

I have created a contact page, and all I want is to make the variable $emailto be dynamique.

What i mean is i have an option page on the backend and I want to let administrator change the contact email.

```
enter code here
if(!isset($hasError)) {

        $emailTo = 'contact@sophrologie.com';
        $subject = 'Formulaire du contact '.$name;
        $sendCopy = trim($_POST['sendCopy']);
        $body = "Nom et prénom: $name \n\nEmail: $email \n\nSujet: $sujet\n\nComments: $comments";
        $headers = 'De : mon site <'.$emailTo.'>' . "\r\n" . 'Répondre à : ' . $email;

        mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers);

        if($sendCopy == true) {
            $subject = 'Formulaire de contact';
            $headers = 'De : <noreply@somedomain.com>';
            mail($email, $subject, $body, $headers);
        }

        $emailSent = true;

    }
```

Now there is what I wanna do :

```
$emailTo = echo wpJediOptions::get_option('my_option', 'email_1');
```

**The problem is we can't use an echo with = operator so what I need to do ???**

EDIT

I have created an option page on the back-end with some input so to show what the administrater is puting in the input.

For exemple i had an input for email, to show this email on a cotact page i need to do this :

```
<li class="ema">E-mail : <?php echo wpJediOptions::get_option('achraf_option', 'mail_1'); ?></li>
```

what i wanna know is how to do the same for this variable $emailTo.

this variable serve to send the contact form to this email.

Comment: Er, remove the `echo` ?!

Comment: see my comment below.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? You want to get the option and output it?

```
$emailTo = wpJediOptions::get_option('my_option', 'email_1');
echo $emailTo;
```

Comment: No, sorry I forgot to tell you I'm using a class named wpJediOptions.

And to show the option I need the echo, thats why i can't figure out how to show my option.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You might have to explain it a bit more. Where do you want to echo out $emailTo? What are you trying to achieve with $emailTo = echo wpJediOptions::get_option('my_option', 'email_1');?

Comment: see my edit in the post.

Comment: Ok, thank you, so about the $emailTo variable. Where is it being set/defined, and where do you want it to be echoed out? What does this variable contain? Where is it being assigned the data?

Comment: I have all the code for the contact form but this variable is setted in the code above with the mail function.